# Pgfpages cleardoublepage

Tags: page-breaking, pgfpages

I need to divide A4 into two A5 pages (landscape) which works fine with pgfpages but i also need special double page (like titlepage) where left half-page is empty and right contains text.
But this page sometimes splits so one part is on the previous page. I tried to use `\cleardoublepage` which doesn't end the whole A4 page (if half empty).
minimal example to clarify: (if text fills even number of A5 pages its fine but if number of pages filled by text is odd, my double page splits)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,text={17cm, 24cm},top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper, landscape, border shrink=5mm]
\begin{document}

{\Large Empty page}

\newpage
{\LARGE Title page}
%end of special double page
\cleardoublepage

{\LARGE text unknown length}

\null\cleardoublepage
%beginning of second special double page
{\Large Empty page}

\newpage
{\LARGE Title page}
%end of second special double page
\null\cleardoublepage
{\LARGE text unknown length}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\cleardoublepage` only does what you want in two-sided printing. So, add option `twoside` to the class options:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
```